# Battery Issue - Low level issue

Tags: mac, battery, unix

I have installed Xubunto instead of Machintosh on my MacBook Pro machine, when i close the screen the apple lamp on the back of my laptop doesn't goes off, and the laptop runs out of power. how can i control this back lamp to be on or off ??, is there away to disable it from my Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple logo lights up when the screen is on, so what's happening is that your screen isn't turning itself off. This usually happens when the power management extensions aren't loaded in the operating system, and issues with sleep are one of the biggest indicator of this.

Have a look at this page : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro. It could be of help. The procedures should remain the same for Xubuntu as for Ubuntu, so don't worry about that.